# There is no on button showing in gnome shell extension

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

How to enable gnome shell extension?.

When i click on gnome shell extension there is no ON button showing `advanced settings` --> `shell extensions`. In a youtube video I saw there is one ON button to enable shell extensions.

[image]i have allready installed gnome tweak tool and everything..

I have want to use user themes for gnome shell, but I am having troubles. I installed the user theme extension, but it doesn't appear to show up under the gnome tweak tool. To confirm that I have the user themes extension installed, here is the feedback I get when I try to install it through terminal again:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Looks like uploading the screenshot didn't work. Can you try again?

Comment: Sorry about the answer -- I misunderstood your question at first. Have you installed gnome-tweak-tool?

Comment: which extension is that?

Comment: It's not an extension, it's just a tool that gives you access to the advanced options for the gnome-shell. It's on the repositories and it's got a gui, so it shouldn't be too hard to figure out what's going on once you've got that.

Comment: I have want to use user themes for gnome shell, but I am having troubles. I installed the user theme extension, but it doesn't appear to show up under the gnome tweak tool. To confirm that I have the user themes extension installed, here is the feedback I get when I try to install it through terminal again:

Comment: i have allready installed gnome tweak tool and evrything

Comment: It's not an extension, it's just the "advanced settings" tool for gnome-shell. You use it to activate and install extensions, change your user theme (I recomend [dark shine](http://satya164.deviantart.com/art/Gnome-Shell-Dark-Shine-266329752) -- you'll need to get gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme -- you can get it from the webupd8 ppa -- and activate it, then you just open the zip file using gnome-tweak-tool).

Comment: What's wrong with me? I couldn't see my last comment, sorry again about that. Have you tried gnome-shell --replace? or logging out and loggin in again? It didn't show up for me either at first, I don't know what fixed it. I might have needed a full restart.

Comment: i restart system many times . but still the same result. how do gnome-shell-replace

Comment: you can either run it from a terminal (but remember to keep the terminal open until you logout or you'll break the shell for the current session and need a hard restart), or you can bind the "Show the run command prompt" setting in the keyboard->shortcuts settings to Alt+F2 (which is the recommended way to do it). I don't think it will do anything if you've already tried restarting your system though.

Comment: am new in ubuntu please tell me .. what should i do with terminal what should i type in terminal. please

Comment: But looking at your screenshot -- I just realised you're still in unity! I've undeleted my previous answer, because it's relevant to you.

Comment: But in reply to the question about the terminal -- I can understand it can be frustrating in a new environment. You open the terminal using 'ctrl+alt+T', and then type 'gnome-shell --replace' (without the quotes) when it opens and prompts you to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a screenshot, just log out of your current session.

If you're on 11.10, click the cog button above where you enter your password, and it will let you select gnome 3 as your shell. Then you'll be able to enjoy a far superior UI to unity for as long as you want.

If you're using 11.04 I've heard you can't go back to unity after using it, because it messes with gtk2 (I don't know -- I never tried to go back), but the process is approximately the same, only this time the selection will be at the bottom of the screen, near where you select the keyboard.

Comment: thank you so much.... that help me ... thank you so much..